# Is there a hypergeometric function in python?

Tags: python, r

Is there any module/function in python that supply the same functionality as the `Hypergeometric Function` in R? (dhyper, phyper, qhyper, rhyper)- [docs for the function in R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Hypergeometric.html)

Comment: [`scipy.stats.hypergeom`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.hypergeom.html) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is implement in scipy.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.hypergeom.html